# Selenium Webdriver Python Difficulty finding elements because node id keeps changing and not given much else

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="node-347146" class="node node-article node-teaser clearfix" about="/books/david-ar-white-chasing-your-god-given-dream" typeof="schema:Article sioc:Item foaf:Document" sliderimagepath="">

<div class="teaser-image">
<a class="clearfix" href="/books/david-ar-white-chasing-your-god-given-dream" style="position:relative;">
<img src='http://www1./sites/default/files/styles/image_xl_640x480/public/media/standard/images/david-ar-white_si.jpg?itok=1ZKuo2_F' alt='' class='img-responsive'> </a> </div>
<div class="teaser-text"><h3><a href="/books/">David A.R. White on Chasing Your God-Given Dream</a></h3></div>
<p>You know him as Pastor Dave from the highly successful movie, God’s Not Dead and its sequel God’s Not Dead 2.&nbsp; With a witty charm powered by the...</p> </div>
```

I cannot use ID because that will change I just need to locate the item consistently but I know article ids will change constantly

Comment: `class="node node-article node-teaser clearfix"` looks pretty useful, and there's a find_element_by_class_name method. See http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: `xpath`s? Sift through the all the `div`s and find ones whose `id` contains node-variable_number_of_digits?

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for fast reply wow. I tried to id by class but I get a compound class error. Also the site has many similar class IDs

Comment: Can you identify the element another way, i.e. it will be the first `<a>` following a `<div class="teaser-image">`?

Comment: instead of using that class name, use the `find_element_by_css_selector` method.

Comment: Automation has to see this href link even when its dynamically changed The site has different node ids for articles but they are usually in same area

Comment: if I use css selector and I want all selectors can I just loop through all css selectors on the page

Comment: div.node.node-article.node-teaser.clearfix